# asp.net MVC 5 controller and form for role model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

this is the controller for Roles, question is how I can create form to insert role named "Admins" from the forms or view. thanks in advance

```
public ActionResult CreateRole()
{
   string Output = "";
   ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
   RoleManager<IdentityRole> RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(db));

   if (!RoleManager.RoleExists("Admins"))
   {
      IdentityResult Result = RoleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Admins"));
      if (Result.Succeeded)
      {
          Output = "the role created";
      }
      else
      {
          int ErrorCount = Result.Errors.Count();
          Output = "Errors is: " + Result.Errors.ToList()[0];
      }
   }
   else
   {
      Output = "the roles exist";
   }
   return Content(Output);
}
```

Comment: what is the problem of this code?

Comment: there is no problem I just need to try this from the view how I can? @HakamFostok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need create a model of data like this:

```
public class NewRole
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

After, you need edit your controllers to send NewRole model and get it with a post method with same name.

```
    public ActionResult CreateRole()
    {

        NewRole newRole = new NewRole();
        return View(newRole);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateRole(NewRole newRole)
    {
        string Output = "";
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(db));

        if (!RoleManager.RoleExists("Admins"))
        {
            IdentityResult Result = RoleManager.Create(new IdentityRole(newRole.Name));
            if (Result.Succeeded)
            {
                Output = "the role created";
            }
            else
            {
                int ErrorCount = Result.Errors.Count();
                Output = "Errors is: " + Result.Errors.ToList()[0];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Output = "the roles exist";
        }

        if (Output == "")
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "tesssst");
            return View(newRole);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect("Suscces url");
        }

    }
```

Finally right click over CreateRole method and press create view.

Create view like this:

[image]

After that you have a simple view, that show your error message. Remember to write some css in your view

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.NewRole

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateRole";
}

<h2>CreateRole</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "LoginText" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

Comment: Here the role write by user will be saved in your line --> IdentityResult Result = RoleManager.Create(new IdentityRole(newRole.Name));

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the ActionName (method name which in your caes `CreateRole`)
From the ContextMenu click `AddView` this will cause dialog to appear
specify your need and accept the default values.
in the view add the following code

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()) {
    <input type="submit" value="Create Role" />
}
```

also you have to add the following attribute above the ActionName, like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateRole()
```

now when you click the 'Create Role' button from the view, your code must be start to executed, you could set a breakpoint at the start of the method to debug it also

NOTE: please also note that you have to add the get action,which will show the view itself
if you did not added it yet, you have to write the following code

```
[ActionName("CreateRole")]
public ActionResult GetCreateRole()
{
    return View();
}
```

Also you need to specify that the view does not take any model, to make this code working.

if you are new to ASP.NET MVC and do not know the basic of it you can consult this greate [article](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started) which learn you how to use MVC

Comment: Not like this I want to pass data from the from and how to manage it in controller

Comment: @waliahmad what data do you need to pass from the View to the controller?